# How can i use a nextjs project with the http protocol on production service

Tags: http, next.js, production, private-network

I am have making a intranet web page that will running on the private network with the nextjs.

But the builded nextjs webapp that running on production level force loaded files of css, js, image on the path by https protocol.

But i have to use http protocol becauece of my project will run on private network.

How can i use a nextjs project with the http protocol on production service.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
It just csp problem
In private network, removed csp